# Frullani integral for $f(x)=e^{-\lambda x }$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have to prove that

$\beta \log(1-\frac{z}{\gamma})=\int_0^\infty (1-e^zx) \frac{\beta}{x} e^{-\gamma x} dx$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

On they book they suggest to note that in $z= 0$ then

$\frac{e^{-(\gamma-z)x}-e^{-\gamma x}}{x}=\int^\gamma_{\gamma-z} e^{-yx} dy$.
How can I conclude ?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your equation? $e^z x$ should read $e^{zx}$

Comment: Another typo? "On they book they suggest to note that in z=0 ..."

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the order of integration:
$$ \begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\int^\gamma_{\gamma-z} e^{-yx} \, dy \, dx &= \int^\gamma_{\gamma-z} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-yx} \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{\gamma-z}^{\gamma} \frac{dy}{y} \\
&= \log{\gamma}-\log{(\gamma-z)} \\
&= -\log{\left( 1-\frac{z}{\gamma} \right)}.
\end{align} $$